# How to linearly interpolate pandas columns values, based on a particular column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like

```
    A       B       C       D
0   1.0     0.50    1.25    1.25
1   1.5     1.30    1.10    1.25
2   2.0     0.40    1.25    1.25
3   2.5     1.50    1.35    1.25
4   3.0     1.70    1.20    1.25
5   3.5     0.90    0.60    0.63
```

Is there an inbuilt pandas function which could help me interpolate values in any of columns in this case `[B,C,D]` based on values on column `'A'`.

For e.g. I need to derive a linearly interpolated value of Column `'B'` when input is `2.25`. (Column `'A'` values are to be used as reference). 
So here my expected answer is interpolated value between `[0.4, 1.50]` from column `'B'`. i.e. **0.95**

I have written a dedicated function to fetch the `(x1,y1) & (x2,y2)` values and then use two slope/intercept formula to get the answer (but I feel this is an overkill and that I am missing some simple function from pandas library).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an `interpolate` functionality in `pandas` that you can use:

```
# set `A` as index for interpolation
df = df.set_index('A')

# insert the new value
x = 2.25
new_idx = sorted(list(df.index) +[x])

df.reindex(new_idx).interpolate('index').loc[x]
```

Output:

```
B    0.95
C    1.30
D    1.25
Name: 2.25, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you @Quang-Hoang . I was missing this simple feature.